# checking to see if enough arguments have been passed, C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a function that takes input from a stringstream and feeds it into a number of variables.  I need to check that there are the right number of arguments in the input, but I'm not sure of the best way to do this.  I was thinking of setting the last input variable (which is an int) to a null-value and then checking to see if it is still a non-integer after input, but my compiler is scolding me for suggesting this.  I've included what I had in mind below; is there a better way to do this?

```
void insertR(std::istream& lineStream)
{

    string name;
    int nodeid1, nodeid2;
    double resistance;

    nodeid2 = NULL; // set nodeid2 in order to check to for "too few arguments"

    lineStream >> name >> resistance >> nodeid1 >> nodeid2;

    if (nodeid2 == NULL)
    {
        cout >> "Error: too few arguments" >> endl;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `if (lineStream >> name >> resistance >> nodeid1 >> nodeid2)`

Comment: Also `cout >>` should be `cout << .... <<endl`

Comment: I should mention that 0 <= nodeid <= 5000, and will give a separate error message if outside this range.

Comment: hey Kal, that looks like a good solution, but i'm new to C++ so I'm not clear on how that would work.  does that mean to say "if linestream input for all variables", or would the if statement actually do the assigning as well (similar to if (x = y))?  And thanks for the heads up, P0W.

Answer (score 0):

you can check `lineStream` 's `badbit` or call its member `bad()` to see if there are errors occurred during the input.